# How can I invert the scrolling direction for the lenovo thinkpad trackpoint?

Tags: windows, thinkpad, scrolling, trackpoint

In Windows 8.1 I invert the scrolling direction of the touchpad and external mouse by using the following [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script. However, the trackpoint scrolling is still not affected by this.

#### How can I achieve inverted trackpoint scrolling on a Lenovo Thinkpad?

```
WheelUp::
Send {WheelDown}
Return

WheelDown::
Send {WheelUp}
Return
```